# Hive on Cosmos global instance return error code 12 in Java client

Tags: fiware

I recently developed a Java client which allow me to query my Hive  tables from a simple url .

Unfortunately , since last Thursday the queries seems to have some issues . From time to time , my query which worked before , doesn't return me anything .

So I decided to take a look at my logs,  and everytime I do a query this occur :

> java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 12, cause: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeExcep
>   tion(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create
>    directory /tmp/hive-root/hive_2015-06-29_09-19-53_268_7855618362212093455. Name node is in safe mode.
>   Resources are low on NN. Safe mode must be turned off manually.

I think the issue come from the node itself , because I didn't do any changes on my code or in my hive tables . What do you think the problem come from ? And what can I do to resolve it ?

Thank you for your reading my question .

Comment: We are facing a problem with the global instance. The HDFS storage is close to the 100% usage. We are working on freeing some space. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It should be working now.

Comment: Thank you for your support , just in time for the demo !

Comment: Good look, @Guillaume!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due the cluster automatically entered in safe mode. We fixed it by freeing/adding some disk space.